# Images not loading in SXA site

Tags: sxa

using `Sitecore 10.3`

This is my local instance.  I have two sites under `/sitecore/content`.
One is from SXA, like this:

```
sitecore
 |_content
   |_Tenant
     |_Site
       |_Home
```

And the other is non-SXA, like this:

```
sitecore
 |_content
   |_MyCompany
     |_Website
       |_Home
```

Both the home pages use the same renderings and same datasources.
The images load fine in the non-SXA page but not in the SXA one.

The database is set to `master` here - `/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings/Site Grouping/Site`

This is a snap of the SXA page:

[image]

As you can see, the image is available in the browser console, right panel, but its showing as a grey block. When I browse the image URL, the image loads with no issues.

There are no other errors in browser console.

Comment: 1) Try to enclose the url between ' or ". 2) Give it a try `background-image`.

Comment: @SumitHelaiya I tried in the console itself. The snap shows an image in inline css. But even images from other components which are img tags, not loading

Comment: check if the page is associated with proper theme and not the default wireframe theme

Comment: @SumitUpadhyay I'm using a custom layout which has its custom css. I do not want any default themes. Should I still be doing any theme changes?

Comment: open the page in Experience Editor, click on the Experience Accelerator Tab, click Theme, see what theme is mapped for the page

Comment: We also ran into the same problem with Sitecore 10.3 XM SXA page -- Image loads fine when browsed with url in the browser but not rendering on to the web page. Any resolution found to this?

Comment: @sukesh are these images loading properly in experience editor? can you please check?

Comment: @Gautam No. No even in experience editor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using a theme, the default wireframe theme might be used.  Check the mock field value for the wireframe theme (/sitecore/media library/Themes/Wireframe).

If it is not empty, please try to use the 'Clear' button, restart Sitecore and check if the issue still exists.